# Is there any way to convert WSDL file into C# interface with operations?

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, wsdl.exe

I am trying to convert WSDL file into C# code like

```cs
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "ServiceSoap", Namespace = "http://test.com/")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "ServiceSoap", Namespace = "http://test.com/" )]
    public interface IServiceSoap
    {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://test.com/ping", RequestNamespace = "http://test.com/", ResponseNamespace = "http://test.com/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://test.com/ping", ReplyAction = "*")]
        string ping();
   }
```

But with `wsdl /serverInterface File:///C:/service.wsdl`, I get the code like this:

```cs
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.7.3081.0")]
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="ServiceSoap", Namespace="http://test.com/")]
    public interface IServiceSoap {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://test.com/ping", RequestNamespace="http://test.com/", ResponseNamespace="http://test.com/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        string ping();
}
```

Could I anyone just let me know what tools can do it? Or what configs I may need for wsdl.exe? Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of pages on how to do this, blogs and tools [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+convert+wsdl+to+c%23+class&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU822AU822&oq=how+to+convert+wsdl+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4911j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) What have you tried, and whats not working for you.

Comment: I have done that search for several days, and it is actually is not that helpful, that's the reason why I ask ...

Comment: What can we tell you that your research doesn't. I mean if something is not working for you then we are likely to give you the exact same information. If you have tried something and its not working then you need to explain exactly what you are trying, the results of your investigation, what you expect to happen, whats happening